# iCalcreator: change category for each event in ics-file

Tags: php, icalendar

I am trying to change the categories for each event of an existing ics-file. I have an array with the new categories and want to loop through each event and assign the new category according to the index.
Therefor I am using [iCalcreator](http://kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/index.php).

```
$event_categories = array();

// ... 
// populating $event_categories with data
// ...

$config = array( "unique_id" => "cat_mod", "filename" => "myical.ics" );
$v = new vcalendar($config);
$i = 0;

$v->parse();
while( $vevent = $v->getComponent( "vevent" )) {
    $vevent->setProperty("categories", $event_categories[$i]);
    $i++;
    continue;
}

$v->returnCalendar();
```

But this does not work. The categories are still the same.

Could anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [summary file](http://rawgit.com/iCalcreator/iCalcreator/master/summary.html) (look for the section “EDIT”). It shows that you need to remember the uid and reinsert the modified event using it. Here is a condensed example:

```
$v = new vcalendar( $config );          
$v->parse();
while( $vevent = $v->getComponent( "vevent" )) {
  $uid = $vevent->getProperty( "uid" );
  // ... change event ..
  $v->setComponent ( $vevent, $uid );
}
```